# XAML objects don't exist in iOS project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I'm trying to do an Android / iOS project with shared XAML. However, my iOS project won't compile. None of the Form objects seem to exist for it. They do, however, exist and work for the Android project.

[image]

How do I make the Form objects available to the iOS project?

Comment: do you have the Forms packages installed in your iOS project?  Does your iOS project have a reference to the shared/PCL Forms project?

Comment: Yes and yes. the References are the Forms project, and then Xamarin.Forms.Core, Xamarin.Forms.Platform, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, and Xamarin.iOS. I created it using the basic Forms app template.

Comment: If this is a shared project, you might just need to switch the active project in the IDE from Droid to iOS.

Comment: Whether the project is active or not, it gives the same error when the project is compiled.

Comment: Check your Xamarin versions both in Visual Studio and on your mac build host. If you move to the latest stable version, you will also have to update XCode to Xcode 8.3.